# Zabbix DB: how events linked to hosts

Tags: zabbix

I want to create the custom report on event by 2 monitoring system.

I know about Zabbix API, but think 
if I request data through the API, then the performance will not be the same if I perform queries directly to the database Zabbix.

I found a table with information about events,

```
SELECT eventid, source, object, objectid, clock, value, acknowledged, ns
FROM zabbix.events
```

Found zabbix.hosts and zabbix.host_inventory.

How is `zabbix.events` linked to `zabbix.hosts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objectid` for trigger events (`source=0`) is the trigger ID, which in turn has function IDs, which in turn have item IDs, which in turn have host IDs.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this link on the Zabbix share : 
https://share.zabbix.com/databases/mysql/zabbix-database-model

Alain updates it pretty fast for every new release, and if you want to do some SQL queries, this is a must have.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer, I have been figuring it out manually, this will be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

The database schema is not documented officially, but you may find some community resources for that - http://zabbix.org/wiki/Database_Schemas. Just keep in mind that's 2.4.3 version. That is likely to be enough to find relations for your case.

Answer (score 0):

information did compilate in this select:

```
SELECT * FROM events
JOIN triggers ON events.objectid = triggers.triggerid
JOIN functions ON functions.triggerid = triggers.triggerid
JOIN items ON items.itemid = functions.itemid
JOIN hosts ON items.hostid = hosts.hostid
WHERE events.source = 0 
AND 
LOWER(hosts.host) like 'mysql%' 
AND events.clock>=unix_timestamp('2017-09-25 09:55:00') 
AND events.clock<=unix_timestamp('2017-09-25 11:00:00') 
ORDER BY events.clock DESC
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a query I created to run against the zabbix db. It joins hosts and hostgroups, and then left joins acknowledged or unacknowledged events. once an event is resolved, it will drop off this query. It pulls for enabled or unreachable hosts.

```
select 

h.name as hostname, 
h.status as hoststatus, 
g.name as groupname, 
hi.alias as hostalias, 
hi.location as hostlocation, 
hi.os as hostos,
dt.idescription as itemdescription,
dt.ikey as itemkey_,
dt.iname as itemname,
dt.hsurl as httpstepurl,
dt.hsname as httpstepname,
dt.tcomments as triggercomments,
dt.tdescription as triggerdescription,
dt.tpriority as triggerpriority,
dt.eventclock as eventclock,
dt.eacknowledged as eventacknowledged


from 
hosts h 
inner join hosts_groups hg on h.hostid=hg.hostid
inner join groups g on hg.groupid = g.groupid
left join host_inventory hi on h.hostid=hi.hostid

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
i.hostid as ihostid,
i.itemid as iitemid, 
i.description as idescription,
i.key_ as ikey,
i.name as iname,
hs.url as hsurl, 
hs.name as hsname, 
t.description as tdescription,
t.url as turl,
t.comments as tcomments, 
t.priority as tpriority,
from_unixtime(e.clock) as eventclock, 
e.acknowledged as eacknowledged
from items i 
left join functions f on i.itemid = f.itemid
left join triggers t on f.triggerid = t.triggerid
right join events e on t.triggerid = e.objectid
left join httpstepitem hsi on i.itemid = hsi.itemid
left join httpstep hs on hsi.httpstepid = hs.httpstepid
inner join problem p on e.eventid = p.eventid

WHERE 
 ((e.acknowledged='0' AND i.status='0' AND r_clock='0') OR (e.acknowledged='1' AND i.status='0' AND r_clock='0'))


) dt ON h.hostid = dt.ihostid

where  (h.status='2' or h.status='0');
```